# State is not defined no-undef ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I keep getting the error `Line 29:  'answers' is not defined  no-undef` and I am not quite sure what's going on or how to fix it (I'm very new to React and JS). Could anyone perhaps explain what this means and give me a few pointers? Thanks!

```
class App extends Component {


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        key: myUUID,
        title: "",
        author: "",
        questions: [],
        answers: []
      }
  }

  addQuestion(){
    questionNum++;
    this.setState({
      answers }, () => {
      this.state.answers.concat("hello")
    });
  }
```

UPDATE: Here's what the new `addQuestion` function looks like

```
  addQuestion(){
    questionNum++;
    this.setState({
      answers: this.state.answers.concat("hello")
    });
  }
```

I call this function when this button is clicked `<button onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add Question</button>`

Now I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think perhaps you mean to write it like this, which will bind `this` to the function with the arrow function:

```
addQuestion = () => {
  questionNum++;
  this.setState({
    answers: this.state.answers.concat("hello")
  });
}
```

or

```
const answers = this.state.answers.concat("hello");
this.setState({ answers });
```

The way you have it written, `answers` is undefined, and `() => {this.state.answers.concat("hello")}` is a callback to `setState`

Comment: Just linking the official docs, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks for them help, I changed it to `this.setState({
  answers: this.state.answers.concat("hello")
});` and no longer get an error when the page is opened but I get an error when the function is called (updates on the OG question)

Comment: @dorkycam see my updated answer. The key part is the `= () => {`

Comment: Awesome this fixed it, Thanks!